# Problemas al intentar instalar la librería php-vips (libvips)

Tags: php

Estoy intentando instalar la librería `libvips`  via `composer`

**Documentación  :**

- https://github.com/libvips/php-vips
- https://libvips.github.io/libvips/install.html

**Entorno :**

- Actualmente estoy haciendo pruebas en local con `XAMPP for Windows PHP 7.4.16`
- Composer `2.0.13`

**Según la documentación debo:**

- activar la extensión  `extension=vips.so` en `php.ini` lo cual ya he
  hecho.
- Crear un archivo `composer.json` con el `require` de la libreria

```html
{
    "require": {
        "jcupitt/vips" : "1.0.7"
      }
}
```

- Ejecutar el comando `composer install`

Pero me parece  lo siguiente :

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'vips.so' (tried:
> C:\xampp\php\ext\vips.so (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo
> especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_vips.so.dll (No se puede
> encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:
> Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1799
> but version 1803 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave
> surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick
> version 1799 but version 1803 is loaded. Imagick will run but may
> behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0 No lock file found. Updating
> dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update
> over composer install if you do not have a lock file. Loading composer
> repositories with package information Updating dependencies Your
> requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires jcupitt/vips 1.0.7 -> satisfiable by jcupitt/vips[v1.0.7].
> - jcupitt/vips v1.0.7 requires ext-vips >=0.1.2 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's vips extension.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\xampp\php\php.ini You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Al parecer debo agregar un `dll`en `C:\xampp\php\ext\vips.so` pero no encuentro por ningún lugar (5 días buscando por Google)

Comment: ¿Ejecutaste el comando `pecl install vips`?

Comment: @sal  no había probado  pero me devuelve lo siguiente
~Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PEAR\REST.php on line 186
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/vips"
install failed´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desafortunadamente la extensión para Windows [no esta lista](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips-ext/issues/35), de hecho a eso se refiere cuando dice *"Para Windows necesitaría algo de trabajo"*.

Entonces, o cambias de lenguaje, o de sistema operativo, o contribuyes haciendo la compilación -que otros no han terminado-, o te limitas a correr comandos con `exec()` o `shell_exec()`.

Comment: Que mala noticia. =(